# PHP MYSQL "more info" button

Tags: php, html, mysql, bootstrap-4

I have a question:

In PHP, HTML and MySQL I have made an overview of products (data from database)
Now each product in this list has a more info button. I want, when I click more info, that a new page is opened and that page should show more info about that product.
How do I make it work that it only shows the info of that particular product?

This is the current code of the table with the overview:

```
    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <h4 class="product-name"><strong> Producten</strong></h4><h4><small></small></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
                                <h6><strong>Datum binnenkomst</strong></h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                <h6><strong>Datum uitgave</strong></h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-2">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
<?php 
include("connection.php");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bedrijven";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo'
                    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2"><img class="img-responsive" style="max-height:80px;" src="' . $row["KVK"] . '">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <h4 class="product-name"><strong> '. $row["Bedrijfsnaam"] .' </strong></h4><h4><small>'. $row["Klantnummer"] .'</small></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
                                <h6><strong>'. $row["BStraatnaam"] .'</strong></h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                <h6><strong>'. $row["BHuisnummer"] .'</strong></h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-2">
                                <a href="Moreinfo.php"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-xs">
                                    More info
                                </button></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr>';
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();?>
```

I hope someone would help me.

It would be nice to learn more and new things;)

Comment: When they click the link redirect them to a different page with the product id as a parameter and based on that id you can get the information from the database.

Comment: you need a `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split up results only print out what you want to show. You can do selective queries with `LIMIT` (for a range) or just make sure you only get one result usually done by using a unique identifier (an auto-incremented ID field) and `WHERE id = 1`.

And in PHP we can use `$_GET['page']`, to get the page parameter from an url like:

```
domain.com/somepage?page=2
```

However remember that this is easily edited by the end user in the location bar and thus should be properly handled in PHP before using it in a SQL query to avoid [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). It be checking with PHP's `is_number` or using something like [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)